# Detect "end: key press in python3

Tags: python-3.5

I am trying to take input infinitely  from user until the user presses end key on the key board. The input can be any data type. for example code below I want to exit the while loop when end is pressed on the key board.

```
    l = []
while 1:
    v = input("Enter the list element")
    l.append(v)
    if int(v)==1:  # instead of checking 1 I want to check for "end" key press 
        break

print("the list is %s" %(l))
```

Would be great if someone can suggest exit on combination of key press as well such as ctrl+e etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pynput` [library](https://pythonhosted.org/pynput/keyboard.html) to detect which key was pressed 
I believe `Input()` could not detect functional keys, (except for `enter` or `backspace`, and etc.)

They have `pynput.keyboard.Listener` to listen to keys

[Additional Info](https://pypi.org/project/pynput/#description)

Comment: how do I use pynput.keyboard   I tried to import I got module not found error and when I tried to install it using sudo apt-get install pynput I got could not locate pynput error on ubuntu

Comment: @Vicky This is `python` library, thus you need to use `pip install pynput` command

Answer (score 0):

Youcan use Exception Handling.

```
try:
     While 1:
           # your code

except KeyboardInterrupt:
      print("Exit")
      exit()
```

This code will loop until you give an keyboard interrupt (ctrl+c)..
For more information refer: https://www.python-course.eu/exception_handling.php